# How to make Firebase Authentication for Android working with Phone number?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

This is my activity that displays edit text fields for verification code and phone number. On click of start button I am not getting any response. 
Thanks in advance.

EditText mPhoneNumberField, mVerificationField;
    Button mStartButton, mVerifyButton, mResendButton;

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
String mVerificationId;

private static final String TAG = "PhoneAuthActivity";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone);

    mPhoneNumberField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_phone_number);
    mVerificationField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_verification_code);

    mStartButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_start_verification);
    mVerifyButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_verify_phone);
    mResendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_resend);

    mStartButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mVerifyButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    mResendButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onVerificationCompleted:" + credential);
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onVerificationFailed", e);
            if (e instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
            } else if (e instanceof FirebaseTooManyRequestsException) {
                Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Quota exceeded.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onCodeSent:" + verificationId);
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;
        }
    };
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            mVerificationField.setError("Invalid code.");
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}

private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
}

private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}

private void resendVerificationCode(String phoneNumber,
                                    PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks,         // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
            token);             // ForceResendingToken from callbacks
}

private boolean validatePhoneNumber() {
    String phoneNumber = mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString();
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNumber)) {
        mPhoneNumberField.setError("Invalid phone number.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (currentUser != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(PhoneNumberActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_start_verification:
            if (!validatePhoneNumber()) {
                return;
            }
            startPhoneNumberVerification(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString());
            break;
        case R.id.button_verify_phone:
            String code = mVerificationField.getText().toString();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(code)) {
                mVerificationField.setError("Cannot be empty.");
                return;
            }

            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId, code);
            break;
        case R.id.button_resend:
            resendVerificationCode(mPhoneNumberField.getText().toString(), mResendToken);
            break;
    }

}
```

This is my code. But it is giving the following exception:
com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.

Answer (score 1):

Try
FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()

instead of
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();